# Process.Start() unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, process.start

I'm using `Process.Start` to start an application that should provide an .COM Object to interact with in VBScript (via  `Set xy = GetObject([...])`).

But if I start the Process with my C# Application, the programm is starting,  but doesn't provide the `.COM` object.  Only if I use the regular Desktop shortcut.

Is there anything i'm missing while using `Process.Start`?

Comment: Process.Start just fires the process, it maybe because its not starting in the same directory as double clicking from the desktop shortcut.

Comment: The shortcut might include some command line parameters to enable the automation server. You should try to start the process in exactly the same way as the shortcut including command line parameters.

Comment: There are no parameters in the Shortcut.  If I create a batch file to start the processes everything works.  but if I execute this .bat in my application, no `.com`  Object is provided...